# Why can't I update HTML list item with Javascript innerHTML property?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I'm trying to learn Javascript and decided to try the `innerHTML` property myself. But the browser seems to ignore the Javascript code. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>JavaScript - Document Object Model </title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="page">
          <h1 id="header">List</h1>
          <h2>Buy groceries</h2>
          <ul id="todo">
            <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
            <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li><li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
            <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
         </ul>
       </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       var thirdItem = getElementById('three');
       var itemContent = thirdItem.innerHTML;
       thirdItem.innerHTML = '<li id="three" class="hot">chicken</li>';
     </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: It's `document.getElementById()` - you have to call it as a method of the `document` object.

Comment: Also you're trying to put an `<li>` inside the `<li>` that's already there - the replacement text should just be `"chicken"`.

Comment: try check errors in browser console

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
var thirdItem = document.getElementById('three');
...
thirdItem.innerHTML = 'chicken';
```

['You might not need jQuery'](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) is a short reference of the JavaScript DOM routines vs. jQuery ones.